# Change white png image to specific colour

Tags: image, photoshop, hue

I have a white png image, which is a part of a n icon.

I would like to change it's colour to get a coloured icon.

I know it is possible with hue/saturation setting, but don't know how to achieve a specific colour output.

I am using Axialis Icon Workshop (I have Photoshop CS5 also). The colourize option along with Hue, Saturation and Brightness adjustments will assist getting any colour output. But I specifically want colour `#3366CC`.

Is there a solution to **convert my white png image to `#3366CC` coloured image**?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This can be easily achieved if you go to the layers panel in Photoshop and select your icon layer. If the icon has a transparent background then select the fx button from the bottom of the layers panel and select color overlay or go to the menu at the top of the Photoshop screen and select Layer > Layer Style > Color Overlay. From the options box select the color box and put in 3366cc instead of the ffffff you have.

This should give you a coloured icon as desired. If this doesn't work let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: Wow thanks... I wonder then why the "replace color" tool is called like that, when this does exactly that, and much better...

Answer (score 2):

You can go to layer style and choose color overlay, but that wont give you the color as you exactly want it, you can go a step further and hold the control key and click on the shape or the image you want to change the color, the shape will be selected, make a new layer on top of the shape or image that you want to change the color then fill in the color with the color that you choose in the layer property and set the mode to overlay, reduce the opacity to 50%. done